# PHP mail handler emailing twice

Tags: php, email

I have a form with a mail handler and it sends 1 form as a email TWICE..... I got a feeling its due to this line of code that redirects the user to a error or a success page if the mail sends or not. (Im not using Mailto)

Here is the line of code that i think is causing the problem:

```
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader);

if(mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader)){
  header("Location: success.html");
} else {
  header("Location: error-enquiry.html");
}
```

Here is my full php:

```
<?php 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$references = $_POST['references'];
$information = $_POST['information'];
$checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n references: $references \n information: $information \n checkbox: $checkbox";
$recipient = "@None of your business";
$subject = "Enquiry Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader);

if(mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader)){
  header("Location: success.html");
} else {
  header("Location: error-enquiry.html");
}

if (isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
  $checkbox = "yes";
} else {
  $checkbox = "no";
}

exit; 
?>
```

I dont know what i have done wrong in this.... Can anyone help me please?

Cheers,
Sean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader); /// <-- Remove this

if(mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader)){
   ...
```

You are sending mail and then sending it again to check the result

Remove the first mail entry

Answer (score 3):

Better to store the result from mail in a variable and check it so you won't send it again

```
$is_mail=mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader);
if($is_mail){
//Redirect to
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty clear. You invoke mail twice: once as direct call to mail function, once in if statement. 2 calls, 2 mails.

Please kill single line call to mail and only keep the call found in if statement to solve issue.

Comment: huh? What line?

Answer (score 0):

You have already called the mail function before checking.

Please remove first line of code

```
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader);
```

and use the mail function like this:

```
 if(mail(...,...,...,...)){....}else{....}
```

for a successfull result.

or assign to a varriable like

```
$email_send=mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader);

if($email_send){....}else{....}
```